# "request-key: Cannot find command to construct key" when accesing NFS mounted volumes

Tags: 12.10, nfs

Since I've upgraded to 12.10 (`3.5.0-17.28-generic 3.5.5`) the next error appear in `auth.log` every time an NFS volume is accessed:

```
request-key: Cannot find command to construct key
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this thread : https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8807

The solution given by Guillaume Rousse helped to get rid of theses error messages.

Comment: You should post the solution...not just a link...